# Updating Hash value in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash, iterator, key, key-value

What i'd like to do is push a bunch of user inputted strings, separated by their spaces to Hash Keys and assign each of those Keys a numerical value from 0 upwards in their order of input. For example;

User input: "a s d f b"

Result:

```
a => 0
b => 1
c => 2
d => 3
f => 4
b => 5
```

But my code is only outputting 0 with no increment, please see my code below;

```
puts "Please enter data:"
text = gets.chomp
words = text.split(" ")
    frequencies = Hash.new(0)

words.each do |k|
    frequencies[k] += 1
end

frequencies.each do |x,y|
    puts x + " " + y.to_s
end
```

Can anyone see what's wrong with the code above?

Comment: How did you get your "result"?  There was no 'c' in the input string, and 'b' was last, yet it is second numerically?

Comment: How can the result have 2 "b" keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default value of every key in this `Hash` is `0`, so by

```
frequencies[k] += 1
```

You are incrementing every value (of non-existing key) from `0` to `1`.

A simple fix is to use an external counter as the value:

```
counter = 0
words.each do |k|
    frequencies[k] = counter
    counter += 1
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work because

```
frequencies[k] += 1
```

Is like

```
frequencies[k]    = frequencies[k] + 1
# ^ set new value   ^ get default value (i.e. 0)
```

The default value never changes, so every key gets the same default value of 0 and adds one to it.

You could explicitly increment the default value each time

```
words.each do |k|
  frequencies[k] = frequencies.default += 1
end
```

But I think the more Rubyish solution is to use the indices of the keys (since that's what the "numerical values" are). `each_with_index` gives you each key with it's corresponding index, and `to_h` turns these pairs into a Hash.

```
frequencies = text.split.each_with_index.to_h
```

egwspiti is correct that older versions of Ruby don't have `Enumerable#to_h`. In that case you can do

```
words.each_with_index do |k, i|
    frequencies[k] = i
end
```

Comment: One side note: `Enumerable#to_h` is available in MRI from version 2.1 and up. No idea about other implementations of ruby.

Answer (score 0):

`frequencies` seems to be a poor choice of variable name from the description.

Any reason why you can't just

```
words = "foo bar baz"
=> "foo bar baz"
words.split.map.with_index.to_h
=> {"foo"=>0, "bar"=>1, "baz"=>2}
```